# How to count the total of each group categorize by set from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I may not use the proper subject of the problem. But here's the detail. I've got 3 tables of data 2 of them are **set name** and **group name**. The rest is data - **user db**. Here's the db.

**set_name**

```
+--------+-----------+
| set_id | set_title |
+--------+-----------+
|   1    |   Set A   |
+--------+-----------+
|   2    |   Set B   |
+--------+-----------+
```

**group_db**

```
+--------+-----------+--------+
| grp_id | grp_title | set_id |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   1    |  Grp. A   |    1   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   2    |  Grp. B   |    1   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   3    |  Grp. C   |    1   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   4    |  Grp. D   |    1   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   5    |  Grp. E   |    1   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
|   6    |  Grp. F   |    2   |
+--------+-----------+--------+
```

**user_db**

```
+--------+-----------+
| usr_id |   grp_id  |
+--------+-----------+
|   1    |     1     |
+--------+-----------+
|   2    |     1     |
+--------+-----------+
|   3    |     2     |
+--------+-----------+
|   4    |     1     |
+--------+-----------+
|   5    |     3     |
+--------+-----------+
|   6    |     4     |
+--------+-----------+
|   7    |     5     |
+--------+-----------+
|   8    |     5     |
+--------+-----------+
|   9    |     5     |
+--------+-----------+
|   10   |     6     |
+--------+-----------+
```

According to the information provided above. I expect a summary table in which count all user and categorize by group and set. For example:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| SET |                    Set A.                  | Set B. |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|GROUP| Grp. A | Grp. B | Grp. C | Grp. D | Grp. E | Grp. F |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| NUM |    3   |    1   |    1   |    1   |    3   |    1   |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|TOTAL|                      9                     |    1   |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
```

And this is how I do.

```
<table>
  <tr>
  <?
    $sql_set=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,count(group_db.grp_id) AS nGrp\n" 
                             . "FROM set_name\n"
                             . "INNER JOIN group_db ON set_name.set_id=group_db.set_id\n" 
                             . "GROUP BY set_name.set_id\n"
                             . "ORDER BY set_name.set_id asc");
    echo "<td>SET</td>";
    while($rec_set=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_set)){
      echo "<td colspan=\"$rec_set[nGrp]\">$rec_set[set_title]</td>";
    }
  ?>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?
    $sql_sGrp=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from group_db\n" 
                              . "WHERE set_id='$rec_set[set_id]'\n" 
                              . "ORDER BY grp_title asc");
    echo "<td>GROUP</td>";
    while($rec_sGrp=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_sGrp)){
      echo "<td>$rec_sGrp[grp_title]</td>";
    }
  ?>
  </tr>
</table>
```

That's it. I don't know how to go further. Please be advice.
Ps. Should I make them all in multilevel array to make it easier?

Comment: Not related to your question, but unless you're embedding this on something that has very little memory, using whitespace makes your code easier to read

Comment: This statement is a fail:  "select *,count(group_db.grp_id) as nGrp 
from set_name inner join group_db on set_name.set_id=group_db.set_id 
order by set_id asc"   Count is an aggregate, you need to group by something for it to know what it's counting by (select * group by * is also quite meaningless).  MySQL has a massive bug in it here, any other database would have told you this doesn't work, MySQL does the wrong thing without an error.

Comment: @Twelfth, well I adjusted the query and it's work for the set name now. The problem is about the group and it's counting beneath. More advice please.

Comment: @DavidWilkins, Was that really hard to read? Tell me how to make it baby read. Thanks.

Comment: @Wilf I've submitted an edit.  Feel free to rollback (if it gets approved) if you don't like it

Comment: @DavidWilkins, Thank you very much. It's a lot easier than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    user_db u
        JOIN
    group_db g ON u.grp_id = g.grp_id
        JOIN
    set_name s ON g.set_id = s.set_id
```

(EDIT: changed qry to this ^ which can be seen here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e749f/4)

And then in PHP:

```
$newArray = array();

while($rec_set=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_set)){
    $newArray[$rec_set['set_title']][$rec_set['grp_title']] += 1;
}
```

which should give you a nice multidimensional array of the results that you can parse through however you want

And to give a table that looks like:

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| SET |                    Set A.                  | Set B. |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|GROUP| Grp. A | Grp. B | Grp. C | Grp. D | Grp. E | Grp. F |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
| NUM |    3   |    1   |    1   |    1   |    3   |    1   |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
|TOTAL|                      9                     |    1   |
+-----+--------------------------------------------+--------+
```

I would use:

```
<tr>
    <td>SET</td>
    <?php foreach($newArray as $set => $group): ?>
    <td colspan="<?=count($newArray[$set])?>"><?=$set?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>GROUP</td>
    <?php foreach($newArray as $set => $group): ?>
    <?php foreach($group as $group_name => $amount): ?>
    <td><?=$group_name?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>NUMBER</td>
    <?php foreach($newArray as $set => $group): ?>
    <?php foreach($group as $group_name => $amount): ?>
    <td><?=$amount?></td>
    <?php $totals[$set] += $amount;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>TOTAL</td>
    <?php foreach($newArray as $set => $group): ?>
    <td colspan="<?=count($newArray[$set])?>"><?=$totals[$set]?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

However, now that I look at how you would actually display it, if you really wanted a table that looked like you put, then a multidimensional array would probably not be the best way to loop through your data since all these loops are UGLY! (And it does not scale too well horizontally as you add more and more sets and groups). I did not check it for accuracy.

Comment: iMakeWebsites, Thank you very much for your sample. Can I have a question here? What is +=1 for?

Comment: This is the summing part of how many are in each set_title/grp_title set first time it makes a $newArray[Set A][Grp. A] it will equal 1, then the second time, instead of replacing the 1 it adds 1 to it, making it 2.

Comment: @Wilf However, now that I look at how you would actually display it, if you really wanted a table that looked like you put, then a multidimensional array would probably not be the best way to loop through your data. However, I updated the answer to include what should probably work to display the table. I did not check it for accuracy.

Comment: iMakeWebsites, Can I have a bit asking? How could I add another row of percentage under the **NUMBER** row???

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<table>';

$rows = array('SET', 'GROUP', 'NUM', 'TOTAL');
$setids = array();
$grp_usercounts = array();
$set_usertotals = array();

foreach($rows as $key => $row){
    echo "<tr> $rows </td>";
    switch ($key){
        case 0: //SET
            $sql = "SELECT s.set_id, set_title, count(g.grp_id) nGrp 
                FROM set_name s 
                JOIN group_db g ON s.set_id = g.set_id   
                group by set_id";
             $sql_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
             while($rec_set=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_set)){
                echo '<td colspan="'.$rec_set['nGrp'].'">'. rec_set['set_title'].'</td>';
                $setids[$rec_set['set_id']] = $rec_set['nGrp'];
            }
            break;

           case 1://GROUP

           foreach($setids as $setid => $val){

            $sql = "SELECT g.grp_id, grp_title, count(usr_id) nUsr
                FROM group_db g
                JOIN user_db u ON u.grp_id = g.grp_id
                where set_id = $setid 
                group by g.grp_id order by grp_title";
            $sql_set = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $total = 0;
            while($rec_set=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_set)){
                echo '<td>'. $rec_set['grp_title'].'</td>';
                $grp_usercounts[$rec_set['grp_id']] = $rec_set['nUsr'];
                $total += $rec_set['nUsr'];
            }   
            $set_usertotals[$setid] = $total;
        }
        break;

    case 2://NUM

        foreach($grp_usercounts as $key => $grp_usercount){
            echo '<td>'. $grp_usercount .'</td>';
        }
        break;

    case 3: //TOTAL

        foreach($set_usertotals as $setid => $set_usertotal){
            echo '<td colspan="'.$setids[$setid].'">'. $set_usertotal .'</td>';
        }
        break;

    }

}

unset($setids);
unset($grp_usercounts);
unset($set_usertotals);

echo '</table>';
```